# Array<byte>^ in Win32

Tags: c++, directx, windows-8, winapi

I have a DirectX 11.1 program which is written for Metro style and I want to convert it to Win32 application. I have used a lot of WinRT libraries and most of them are founded for HWND. but I still have an issue:

on Metro Style app, for using HLSL files, this is what I was used:

```
inline Platform::Array<byte>^ ReadFile(Platform::String^ path)
{
    using namespace Platform;

Array<byte>^ bytes = nullptr;

FILE* f = nullptr;
_wfopen_s(&f, path->Data(), L"rb");
if (f == nullptr)
{
    throw ref new Exception(0, "Could not open file on following path : " + path);
}
else
{
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    auto pos = ftell(f);
    bytes = ref new Array<byte>(pos);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // read data into the prepared buffer
    if (pos > 0)
    {
        fread(&bytes[0], 1, pos, f);
    }
    // close the file
    fclose(f);
}
return bytes;
}
```

but I don't know the equivalent of Array `Array<byte>^` for Win32 (hwnd) style app.
any guide is highly appreciated

Comment: This is a generic WinRT/C++ question, nothing particularly specific to games.

Comment: `std::vector<T>` is probably the closest equivalent to `Array<T>`

Comment: You should take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) and the associated [tutorial series](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of that :

```
std::vector<unsigned char> ReadFile(std::wstring path)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> bytes;
    ...
    _wfopen_s(&f, path.c_str(), L"rb");
    ...
    bytes.resize(pos);
    ...
    fread(bytes.data(), 1, pos, f);
    ...
    return bytes;
}
```